# Custom Tab Bar in SwiftUI not maintaining view state upon switching tabs

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I've created a custom tab bar in SwiftUI, but I'm facing an issue where the view reloads every time I switch between tabs (ALL or FOLLOWING). I want to maintain the state of the views to keep bandwidth usage minimal. I've tried implementing the zIndex method as suggested in another Stack Overflow post, but it didn't solve the issue.

Here's my code for the custom tab bar and the view:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct FeedTabBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: { selectedTab = 0 }) {
                    Text("All")
                        .fontWeight(selectedTab == 0 ? .bold : .regular)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                
                Button(action: { selectedTab = 1 }) {
                    Text("Following")
                        .fontWeight(selectedTab == 1 ? .bold : .regular)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 4)
                .clipped()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 0.2), value: selectedTab)
                .offset(x: selectedTab == 0 ? -UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4 : UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4)
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIPullToRefresh

class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab = 0
    
    var selectedTabBinding: Binding<Int> {
        Binding(
            get: { self.selectedTab },
            set: { self.selectedTab = $0 }
        )
    }
}

struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var feedViewModel = FeedViewModel()
    @State private var isInitialLoad = true
    let user: User
    @State private var isUploadPostViewPresented = false
    @StateObject var allPostsManager = PostManager()
    @StateObject var followingPostsManager = PostManager()
    @StateObject var airportData = AirportData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                FeedTabBar(
                    selectedTab: $feedViewModel.selectedTab
                )
                Divider()
                
                ZStack {
                    RefreshableScrollView(showsIndicators: false, onRefresh: { done in
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                            self.allPostsManager.refreshPosts()
                            done()
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack(spacing: 8) {
                            ForEach(allPostsManager.posts, id: \.self) { post in
                                PostCard(post: post, user: user)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 8)
                        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    }
                    .zIndex(feedViewModel.selectedTab == 0 ? 1 : 0)
                    .opacity(feedViewModel.selectedTab == 0 ? 1 : 0)
                    
                    RefreshableScrollView(showsIndicators: false, onRefresh: { done in
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                            self.followingPostsManager.refreshPostsFollowing()
                            done()
                        }
                    }) {
                        VStack(spacing: 8) {
                            ForEach(followingPostsManager.posts, id: \.self) { post in
                                if user.isFollowing(post.username) {
                                    PostCard(post: post, user: user)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 8)
                        .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    }
                    .zIndex(feedViewModel.selectedTab == 1 ? 1 : 0)
                    .opacity(feedViewModel.selectedTab == 1 ? 1 : 0)
                }
                .id(feedViewModel.selectedTab)
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Image("logo")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(height: 25)
                            .padding(.bottom)
                    }
                }
                .overlay(
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: UploadPostView(tabIndex: feedViewModel.selectedTabBinding, airports: airportData.airports),
                        isActive: $isUploadPostViewPresented,
                        label: {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    )
                )
                .overlay(
                    Button(action: {
                        isUploadPostViewPresented = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .regular))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .shadow(radius: 8)
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, 16)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16),
                    alignment: .bottomTrailing
                )
            }
            .onAppear {
                if isInitialLoad {
                    allPostsManager.fetchPosts()
                    followingPostsManager.fetchPostsFollowing()
                    isInitialLoad = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Tried to implement zIndex and it did not work. Even went to ChatGPT and it could not figure it out.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You mention "another Stack Overflow post", can you [edit] and provide a link?

Comment: you ask about "maintaining view state" but then say you want to "keep bandwidth usage minimal". I assume your question is about *caching your data loading*, right?